# Rowcount in target file, how?

Tags: ssis, rowcount

I have a SSIS package that reads from a flat file source. The target file is also a flat file.

I want to count the rows that are written in the target file.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RowCount for that. Below links may help you

http://www.daveturpin.com/2009/10/writing-query-row-count-to-flat-file-in-ssis-part-i/

http://www.programmersedge.com/?p=1492

Comment: I created a data flow that counts the rows with the RowCount component. It stores the value in a user variable, defined at package scope. But when the next data flow wants to store the user value, it stores no value (zero rows). What goes wrong then ?

Comment: When spending more time, I discovered more and more of SSIS. The solution is very simple. The 2nd data flow starts with a Script Component having one custom output column. In the script set the output column to the value from the variable. Then attach the Script Component to the Flat File Destination and voila, it works.